# Application_Error is getting called twice recently

Tags: c#, global-asax, application-error

I have gone through almost all of the old post for Application_Error.
But the issue that I have is, I checked the error log history and this never happened before. The only upgrade we had was .net framework 4.0 to 4.6.1.

I have done following steps already -

1. Checked fiddler for any 404
2. Checked Request.Url.AbsoluteUri

Here is the code in my custom page -

```
private bool SetErrorException(ref string className)
{           
    Exception objError = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

    if(objError != null)
    {
        int iErrorNumber = 10202;  
        string sClassName = objError.TargetSite.ReflectedType.ToString(); 
        string sMethodName = GetMethodName(objError.TargetSite.ToString());
        string sErrorMessage = objError.Message;
        if(m_objErrorControl.ErrorText.Length <=0)
        {
            m_objErrorControl.ErrorText = sErrorMessage;
        }
        if (Request.RawUrl != null)
            sErrorMessage += " (URL: " + Request.RawUrl + ")";

        ABException abException = new ABException(iErrorNumber,sClassName,sMethodName,sErrorMessage, objError);
        abException.Severity = ABException.eSeverity.fatal;

        m_objErrorControl.ExceptionToLog = abException;
        Server.ClearError();
        className = sClassName;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Inside Application_Error

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.Transfer("~/Error.aspx");
}
```

I would really appreciate any suggestion for this one.

Comment: If you log the `Server.GetLastError()` exception in the global `Application_Error(...)` method, you should be able to determine the source of the duplicate call

Comment: @sly Because I'm clearing server error, I won't see any exception again.

Comment: Can the issue be reproduced on your local development pc or test site? If so, you can temporarily comment out the clearing of the server error just for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: @sly it is again showing same error.

Comment: Can you share the exception full stack trace? Also, any reason in particular that you're using `Server.Transfer` instead of `Response.Redirect`?